# Is showFromTabBar method deprecated in ios 8?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiactionsheet

I want to implement showFromTabBar method to show the action sheet from a tabbar item.Is showFromTabBar method is deprecated in ios 8 and is there any replcement for this? If not is there any other way to show the action sheet except popping form the bottom of the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's deprecated. Have a look at [UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet)

Comment: Is there any replacement for this ?

Answer (score 0):

from [iOS Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIActionSheet/showFromTabBar:)

```
- (void)showFromTabBar:(UITabBar *)view
```

Displays an action sheet that originates from the specified tab bar.

Parameters
view
The tab bar from which the action sheet originates.
Discussion
The appearance of the action sheet is animated.

On iPad, this method centers the action sheet in the middle of the screen. Generally, if you want to present an action sheet relative to a tab bar in an iPad application, **you should use the `showFromRect:inView:animated:` method instead.**

Availability
Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
Deprecated in iOS 8.3.

Comment: Yes the description is right but i want to know if there is any other method as a replacement with some changes or is it completely deprecated. And if there is any other way to show the action sheet in iphone except popping up from the bottom?

Comment: i am also waiting for its replacement but still this method works fine